# python flask dict.data?

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, auth

пытаюсь сделать приложение по этому тутору 
https://www.codementor.io/olawalealadeusi896/restful-api-with-python-flask-framework-and-postgres-db-part-1-kbrwbygx5
Есть там нечто на подобии этого

```
from flask import request, json, Response, Blueprint, g
from ..models.UserModel import UserModel, UserSchema
from ..shared.Authentication import Auth


user_schema = UserSchema()
user = UserModel.get_one_user(user_id)
ser_user = user_schema.dump(user).data
```

Класс схемы

```
class UserSchema(Schema):

    """
    User schema
    """

    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    email = fields.Email(required=True)
    password = fields.Str(required=True)
    created_at = fields.DateTime(dump_only=True)
    modified_at = fields.DateTime(dump_only=True)
    blogposts = fields.Nested(BlogpostSchema, many=True)
```

на что мне пайчарм говорит
unresolved attribute reference 'data' for class 'dict'

Погуглил что есть у этого dict. Никакого data я там не нашел.

теперь не могу понять откуда автор туториала это взял и как заставить приложуху работать

Comment: Попробуйте без `.data`. Возможно у вас какая-то из библиотек другой (более новой) версии чем у автора туториала.

Comment: Я хоть и не был уверен, что это поможет, я всетаки попробовал, и это не помогло

Comment: Я посмотрел код по ссылке, там `ser_user` передается в функцию `custom_response`, где этот объект передается в `json.dumps`. По сути смысл операции - данные пользователя преобразовать в словарь, а потом этот словарь преобразовать в json строку, которую уже вернуть как ответ на запрос. Не знаю что вы пробовали, и что у вас не получилось, но вариант `ser_user = user_schema.dump(user)` должен работать.